# Magento Admin is way too slow

Tags: admin-panel, optimization

I upgraded my Magento 1.4 to Magento 1.9.2.2. Upgrade completed successfully but after upgrading, admin panel is too slow. Sometimes, up to 1.3 minutes.

I enabled Magento profiler. Most time consuming calls were these:

```
Code Profiler                                   Time     Cnt Emalloc   RealMem
mage                                            33.0621  1   0         0
mage::dispatch::routers_match                   32.9778  1   0         0
mage::dispatch::controller::action::predispatch 25.1045  1   9,281,168 9,175,040
DISPATCH EVENT:controller_action_predispatch    25.0586  1   3,260,744 2,621,440
```

I read some articles about speeding up Magento admin panel. Enabling cache and disabling extensions are done. When I disabled extensions, the speed significantly grow. But disabling them one by one didn't make any difference.

What should I do to find the bottleneck(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.4 to 1.9 is a big jump, you are probably simply going out of computational resource and you need a better hosting.

If you want to make more tests on disabling extensions just make sure you are turning them off by modifying the xml files in `app/etc/modules`. JUst open the extension you wish to disable and set `<active>` tag to `false`. Manually flush the cache at each step by removing the content of `var/cache` directory (do NOT remove the cache folder itself).

If you get errors after disabling a module just turn it back on to fix.

Disabling from backend **only disables their output**, but **they remain active**.

Also check your cache engine, using Redis may result a in good performance boost.

For frontend you can use MSP LTS2 Full-Page Cache module: https://github.com/magespecialist/lts2

If you already did this, please make a better profiling with AOE_Profiler: https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Profiler

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have no problem in frontend. Also I disabled extensions by modifying `app/etc/modules`. Cache cleared manually from both `var/cache` and `/tmp/magento/var/cache`. I have another Magento installation on this server as well with no problem.

Comment: Use AOE_Profiler to profile in a better way your store:  https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Profiler . The info you gave are not enough to guess what is wrong.

Comment: The extension was brilliant! I've found that two extensions were checking for notifications and updates from their external web services. I disabled them and everything's looks fine now. Thanks.

Comment: AOE_Profiler saved my life a lot of time ;)